# Интеграция liqpay-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, liqpay

Решил попробовать изучить `liqpay-python`, мне необходимо сгенерировать qr-код для оплаты и попытавшись выполнить код по оф. документации понял, что там мало подробностей да и возможно код вообще не рабочий, если кто знает прошу помочь мне.

> Я попытался выполнять этот код взяв его же с оф. документации:

```
from liqpay import LiqPay

public_key = 'sandbox_i4...'
private_key = 'sandbox_h9...'

liqpay = LiqPay(public_key, private_key)
res = liqpay.api("request", {
"action"         : "payqr",
"version"        : "3",
"amount"         : "1",
"currency"       : "USD",
"description"    : "description text",
"order_id"       : "order_id_1"
})
```

> При выполнении у меня произошла ошибка:

```
Возникло исключение: ImportError
cannot import name 'LiqPay' from 'liqpay' (C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\liqpay\__init__.py)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\g.py", line 1, in <module>
    from liqpay import LiqPay
```

> Но согласно документации [ссылка](https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/aquiring/payqr/doc), которая размещена на сайте я делаю всё правильно. В ином случае если бы я не импортировал модуль `LiqPay` с `liqpay`, что я и попытался сделать, у меня происходит ошибка:

```
Возникло исключение: NameError
name 'LiqPay' is not defined
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\g.py", line 6, in <module>
    liqpay = LiqPay(public_key, private_key)
```

> С использованием этого кода:

```
import liqpay

public_key = 'sandbox_'
private_key = 'sandbox_'

liqpay = LiqPay(public_key, private_key)
res = liqpay.api("request", {
"action"         : "payqr",
"version"        : "3",
"amount"         : "1",
"currency"       : "USD",
"description"    : "description text",
"order_id"       : "order_id_1"
})
```

> Писать в поддержку LiqPay не имеет смысла ( так как они сами в этом не разбираются ), может кто знает как мне помочь?
> Для тех кто попытается мне помочь, ссылка на документацию по использованию liqpay api - [сслыка](https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/aquiring/payqr/doc), ссылка на исходный код liqpay api в python - [ссылка](https://github.com/liqpay/sdk-python#readme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема, похоже, в том, что через `pip` ставится не та версия, которая доступна через `GitHub`, а урезанная, которая для `Python 2.x` на самом деле.

```
> ls cp /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/liqpay/

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/liqpay/:
__init__.py  liqpay.py  __pycache__/  test.py

> cat /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/liqpay/liqpay.py

"""
LiqPay Python SDK
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
supports python 2.7.x version
requires requests module
"""
...
```

Но там вообще исходники маленькие, вы можете просто скачать их к себе [из GitHub](https://github.com/liqpay/sdk-python/tree/master/liqpay), выберите там версию, соответствующую вашей версии питона:

- liqpay.py для Python 2
- liqpay3.py для Python 3

И можете тогда либо попробовать подгрузить библиотеку из скачанного локального файла, либо прямо всё содержимое файла к себе закопипастить, оно довольно небольшое. При копипасте `LiqPay` удаётся инстанциировать без вопросов, я пробовал в `Google Colab`.